# Animate parent sticky div to a certain height when some children are hidden

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, css-animations

I am trying to implement some animation on a sticky section of divs, but I don't want to hide all children divs inside. I am posting a JSFiddle to exemplify the problem (**EDIT**): https://jsfiddle.net/vgeq7xx4/8/

The three divs above the content (textFeed) should be always visible. The jQuery snippet should hide some (in our case three) but not all of the divs inside the sticky one when scrolling. This means that the height of the second section varies with its visible content and the third one (the tabs) should be adjusted just below when scrolling.

There should be a way to animate the sticky div in the middle when scrolling. What I mean is that dynamically reducing its height should be made a bit slower than the usual default browser speed.

**EDIT**: I have made some progress and I updated my example above. It turns out to be impossible to animate elements hidden with `display: none`; I didn't succeed either when trying to set my height dynamically. Instead I decided to animate `max-height` by setting a larger value that would never get reached both in my minimal and maximal cases. However, the problem now is that the animation works when I scroll back to the initial position (to the top), it doesn't animate when I scroll down the page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var navbar = $(".header").outerHeight();

  $(".contentWrapper").css("margin-top", function() {
    return navbar;
  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
      if(!$(".contentWrapper").hasClass("scrolled")) {
        $(".contentWrapper").addClass("scrolled");
        $(".about").css("display", "none");
        addSticky();
        calculateHeights();
      }
    }
    else {
      if($(".contentWrapper").hasClass("scrolled")) {
        $(".contentWrapper").removeClass("scrolled");
        $(".about").css("display", "block");
        removeSticky();
        calculateHeights();
      }
    }
  });
});

function calculateHeights() {
  $(".contentWrapper").css("margin-top", Math.max($(".header").outerHeight(), 0 - $(this).scrollTop()));
}

function addSticky() {
  $(".myClass").addClass("sticky");
  $(".tabs").css("position", "fixed");
  $(".myClass").addClass("animateSticky");

  $(".tabs").css("margin-top", $(".myClass").height());
}

function removeSticky() {
  $(".myClass").removeClass("sticky");
  $(".tabs").css("position", "relative");
  $(".myClass").removeClass("animateSticky");

  $(".tabs").css("margin-top", "0");
}
```

What am I missing to make the animation work when scrolling the page in both directions? Thanks in advance!